# Why halve the objective function for Lasso?

Tags: lasso

The objective function of Lasso is often presented by:
$ f(\boldsymbol{b}) = \color{red}{\frac{1}{2}} (\boldsymbol{y} - \boldsymbol{Xb})^T (\boldsymbol{y} - \boldsymbol{Xb}) + \lambda ||\boldsymbol{b}||_1$

I understand that scaling the residual sum of squares by half doesn't affect the LASSO estimate. But why to write it like this? In "The Elements of Statistical Learning" (p. 93) , it's explained that scaling was done out of "convenience" without any further explanation.

Comment: The $1/2$ will be cancelled by $2$ generated by taking partial derivative of $f(b)$ with respect to $b$.

Answer (score 1):

In some sense, this is a mathematics version of [code golf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf). You get to save ONE character when writing later math using the $\frac{1}{2}$ objective function.

#### Motivating example:

Consider two optimization problems A and B:

- Optimization problem A

\begin{equation}
 \begin{array}{*2{>{\displaystyle}r}}
 \mbox{minimize (over $x$)} & x^2 \\
 \end{array}
\end{equation}

- Optimization problem B:
  \begin{equation}
   \begin{array}{*2{>{\displaystyle}r}}
   \mbox{minimize (over $x$)} & \frac{1}{2}x^2 \\
   \end{array}
  \end{equation}

Problems A and B have the same solution since any increasing, [monotonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function) transformation of the objective function will have the same solution.

The only difference is the purely aesthetic one that the first order condition for Problem A is $2x = 0$ while the first order condition for Problem B is $x = 0$. The latter has one less character.